# How would graphics be displayed when creating a game without an engine or library?

Tags: c#, console, window

Let's say that someone decides to create a game without a game engine or library of any sort.

1. C# (or any popular language) is used
2. They have 2D sprites and 3D models with animations
3. They aren't sure of what IDE to use

Based on this information how would they get images displayed onto the screen?

I imagine that a console window would be out of the picture. (Pun intended)

Comment: The first answer is: "don't"! There's a reason those engines and libraries exist, the API for doing it yourself is *horrible*. The real answer I posted :)

Comment: Is there any system context to your question, e.g. an Amiga or Commodore system, or are you assuming something running Windows 8.2 Professional Ultimate 64 Enhanced Plus?

Comment: What's with the third-person question - are you asking for a "friend"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a console window would be out of the question :)

You need to access the built-in Graphics API. On Windows computers, this is DirectX. On other operating systems, it is typically OpenGL.

Both APIs are very cumbersome, and are completely different. Without a library you typically have to be in C/C++ to use them.

As far as IDEs it depends on what you are developing for. Visual Studio is fine for windows, others you need to find something that compiles for it (probably using gcc). Anything will work, its just standard native code.

Good luck!